# Use SoundJS without the preloader functionality

Tags: javascript

Does anyone have an example of how to use SoundJS without using preloaderJS.

I am sad to see that on [Git hub](https://github.com/CreateJS/SoundJS/tree/master/examples) they only have examples where they use the preloader which I don't need.

I am trying the following but the sound instance is not playing:

> var instance = createjs.SoundJS.play("/sounds/mysound.mp3"); //value
>   value of instance.playState results in "playFailed"

Anyone know how to get a more specific error message?

Answer (score 2):

I know this is a very old post, but:

If you are not using PreloaderJS, you need to register the sound first via registerSound():

```
    createjs.Sound.registerSound("/sounds/mysound.mp3", "mysoundID");
```

Then, when you want to trigger it:

```
    createjs.Sound.play("mysoundID");
```

Also, you might want to create an ogg version ("|" as the delimiter) of the file and register both under the same ID:

```
    createjs.Sound.registerSound("/sounds/mysound.mp3|/sounds/mysound.ogg", "mysoundID");
```

*SoundJS will determine which one to call, based off of the current browser.

For more info:
http://www.createjs.com/Docs/SoundJS/classes/Sound.html

Answer (score 0):

Yep, reviving from the dead as the question itself is still sound (ha! pun).

As of SoundJS 0.6.1 (from the docs at http://createjs.com/docs/soundjs/classes/Sound.html):

"**Registering and Preloading**
Before you can play a sound, it must be registered. You can do this with registerSound, or register multiple sounds using registerSounds. If you don't register a sound prior to attempting to play it using play or create it using createInstance, the sound source will be automatically registered but playback will fail as the source will not be ready. If you use PreloadJS, registration is handled for you when the sound is preloaded. It is recommended to preload sounds either internally using the register functions or externally using PreloadJS so they are ready when you want to use them."

Which is rather problematic when developing sound-rich applications on mobile devices with limited memory, like a 512MB iPad Mini for example.

This is where other sound libraries, like Howler, become good alternatives.